# Spring MVC string not displayed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to learn Web Development using Java and this is my first program in Java Web. 
I used the Maven Project in Netbeans and added Spring Framework.
it's just a simple hello world but the message in controller.java is not displayed in index.htm when run. I followed a tutorial from the web but mine doesn't work.
what could be the problem ??

this is what's in my controller

```
@Controller
public class sampClass {

@RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView printWelcome(){
        String message = "Hello World";
        return new ModelAndView("index", "message", message);
}
}
```

and my view is simply

```
Message: ${message}
```

then the output is simply

Message:

Comment: your page is index.htm , i think u should use index.jsp to work it

Comment: i think it's ok, coz if i use index.jsp in the url, the other index file(web/index.jsp) will be the one to be executed. plus WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp is automatically turned to index.htm when run, if my observation is correct..

Comment: @yano: it depends a lot on your configuraion, so that I'm not sure. However, trying to clear the cache of the browser by Ctrl-Shift-R maybe a good start.

Comment: oh, you need to differentiate the .jsp file with the .html file. Only .jsp file gets processed by server, therefore only params passed to .jsp file will get processed. You won't be able to do the same thing with pure html.

Comment: @HoàngLong it's not an html file, it's .jsp actually it's just that when deployed it's address is index.htm

Comment: @yaho: ok  then it's fine. Have you found the problem yet? If not, I think the applicationContext & web.xml file configuration is needed to be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in applicationContext.xml
the annotation was not declared

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample"/>
```

Comment: well... if component-scan doesn't exists, you won't be able to use `@Controller` to map action.. It works most likely because it's the index file

Answer (score 0):

You may need this on the top of your JSP file:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
```

in order to enable ELI expressions as `${message}`